# MySQL. Products not sold in a period

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I am learning MySQL and I have a question.
I have this following assignment and it's pretty new to me, but logically it's easy.

I have the following table:

```
 id          article_id   quantity     date_sold   price
  1                1            2      2014-05-05    200
  2                2            4      2014-05-12    800
  3                3            5      2014-05-02     35
  4                4            10     2014-05-18     60
  5                5            20     2014-05-23     20
  6                6            2      2014-05-20     26
  7                7            1      2014-05-14     10
  8                8            2      2014-05-12     30
  9                9            6      2014-05-11     12
  10               10           2      2014-05-08      6
```

And the question sounds like this "Determine the article not sold in a given period.
The result would pretty much sound like this:
Between 2014-05-10 and 2014-05-20, article 1, 3, 5, 10 have not been sold.

Comment: Hint:  You can use a `group by` with a `having` clause.  Or, you could use a `not exists` condition in the `where` clause.

Comment: ...or an exclusion join

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you show me an example of the group by with a having?

Comment: @Strawberry Can you elaborate?

Comment: I could google it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  SELECT * from table1
  WHERE id NOT IN ( select id FROM table1 WHERE
             `date_sold` BETWEEN '2014-05-10' and '2014-05-20')
```

this will give you result of articles which have not been sold between the given dates.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b7df/2)