# Postgres - Return products not sold recently (more efficient query)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find products in our database that have not been sold since 2019.
The VIEW(itemsales) that I have consist of multiple columns (80 to be exact)
I found a similar question [MySQL. Products not sold in a period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857059/mysql-products-not-sold-in-a-period).
Sample of my view below

```
+----+--------+------------+------------+
| id | itemid | description | salesdate  |   + more columns
+----+--------+------------+------------+
|  1 |     10 | maltesers  | 1/12/2018  |
|  2 |     11 | kitkat     | 10/15/2018 |
|  3 |     12 | mars       | 1/12/2018  |
|  4 |     13 | ferrero    | 3/3/2018   |
|  5 |     12 | mars       | 12/31/2019 |
|  6 |     10 | maltesers  | 2/28/2019  |
|  7 |     16 | milk       | 6/20/2020  |
|  8 |     17 | buttons    | 12/23/2020 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+    + 100k rows
```

My query is below:

```
SELECT distinct description, itemid
FROM itemsales
WHERE itemid not in ( select itemid FROM itemsales WHERE
                 salesdate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' and current_date)
```

The problem is the view has probably 100,000+ rows and when I run the query above, it's taking ages to return a result.
Is there any other query to view the products not sold recently without altering tables? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the `explain` for that query, please? And is it a materialized view?

Comment: It would also help to see the `create view` statement, and the schema of any tables it references. Indexing will help.

Answer (score 1):

One method is aggregation:

```
select itemid, description
from itemsales
group by itemid, description
having max(salesdate) < '2019-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is while the query underlying the view can be indexed, the view itself cannot not. Without seeing the query, it's `explain`, and the schemas I can't say how much this matters. But you can solve it with a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html).

While a view is syntax sugar for a complex query, a materialized view copies the results of the query to a table. That table can then be indexed for performance. The downside is the materialized view has to be manually refreshed. For statistical data this often is not a problem. Depending on how often a view is used, refreshing even every few seconds can bring big performance boosts.

You can try out a materialized view with salesdate indexed.

```
begin

create materialized view m_itemsales as select ...;

create index m_itemsales_salesdate on m_itemsales(salesdate);

commit;
```

Then use [Gordon's improved query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62561694/14660) and see if that helps performance. If it does, replace itemsales with m_itemsales and set up a scheduled job to `refresh materialized view itemsales`.